# MSBuild framework after updating Xamarin

Tags: macos, msbuild, operating-system, xamarin

After updating Xamarin I'm getting this error while building:

```
Construcción fallida. Runtime 'Mono 3.2.5' does not have the MSBuild '4.0' framework installed
```

I get this other if I try to open a xml layout:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Xaml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'System.Xaml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
```

I cannot find anything in Google but this unresolved item:

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=17449

Any idea? My Os is Mac Os and it's an Android project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same error 10 minutes ago after updating Xamarin as well.

Installing the current Beta of Xamarin Studio (4.2.3) solved the problem.

To install it, you need to switch to **Beta** by clicking on:

Check For Updates -> Update Channel: Beta -> Switch Channel. Then restart Xamarin.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should not switch to Beta that easily!
Try restarting the Xamarin Studio first. This solved the problem for me.

Comment: How do you figure that OP is using a beta?